# C# CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync fails BadRequest Setting offer throughput or autopilot on container is not supported for serverless accounts

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

C# **CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync** fails to create Azure Cosmos Db container.  I am trying to run this example: [Hierarchical partition keys in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3%2Cbicep)

> Error:  Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: c9cfa8db-525b-420e-b765-009a43cd8271; Reason: (Setting offer throughput or autopilot on container is not supported for serverless accounts.

```
private static async Task AddContainerTestAsync()
{
    try { 
        var keys = new List<string> { "/source", "/key" };

        // List of partition keys, in hierarchical order. You can have up to three levels of keys.
        List<string> subpartitionKeyPaths = keys;

        // Create a container properties object
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(
            id: "test_container",
            partitionKeyPaths: subpartitionKeyPaths
        );

        // Create a container that's subpartitioned by TenantId > UserId > SessionId
        Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container = await cosmosDb.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerProperties, throughput: 400);
        Console.WriteLine($"created: {container.Id}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error CreateContainer : {e.Message} {e.StackTrace}.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the container manually and noticed that RU throughput is not specified.  I removed this and it worked fine.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container = await cosmosDb.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerProperties);
```

I didn't see that mentioned in the article anywhare.